# How to compare 3 columns of DataFrame together, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have below dataframe and I want to compare 3 columns value & update True/False in another column "Id_Name_Table_Matching"

Below my code:

```
L1_ID = ['Region', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']
L1_Name = ['Region', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']
L1_Table = ['Region', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'dimId': L1_ID, 'dimName': L1_Name, 'sqlTableColumn': L1_Table})
```

I want to update true in "Id_Name_Table_Matching" if all columns value matches else false.
I need script like below:

```
DF1['Id_Name_Table_Matching'] = DF1['dimId'] == DF1['dimName'] == DF1['sqlTableColumn']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare first columns with second, then with last and chain boolena masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
DF1['Id_Name_Table_Matching'] = (DF1['dimId'] == DF1['dimName']) & 
                                (DF1['dimId'] == DF1['sqlTableColumn'])
```

General solution for compare multiple columns defined in list - all filtered columns compare by first one by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and then check if all values per rows are `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
cols = ['dimId','dimName','sqlTableColumn']
DF1['Id_Name_Table_Matching'] = DF1[cols].eq(DF1[cols[0]], axis=0).all(axis=1)
print (DF1)
    dimId dimName sqlTableColumn  Id_Name_Table_Matching
0  Region  Region         Region                    True
1    Col2    Col2           Col2                    True
2    Col3    Col3           Col3                    True
3    Col4    Col4           Col4                    True
4    Col5    Col5           Col5                    True
```

**Detail**:

```
print (DF1[cols].eq(DF1[cols[0]], axis=0))
   dimId  dimName  sqlTableColumn
0   True     True            True
1   True     True            True
2   True     True            True
3   True     True            True
4   True     True            True
```

Answer (score 3):

Look if this helps. Using [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df["Id_Name_Table_Matching"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dimId == x.dimName == x.sqlTableColumn, axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dimId dimName sqlTableColumn  Id_Name_Table_Matching
0  Region  Region         Region                    True
1    Col2    Col2           Col2                    True
2    Col3    Col3           Col3                    True
3    Col4    Col4           Col4                    True
4    Col5    Col5           Col5                    True
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, `T`ranspose with `.nunique()` like this:

```
DF1.T.nunique().le(1)

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
dtype: bool
```